# WebAudio API "createOscillator" is not a function. Where's it gone?

Tags: javascript, audio, web

Trying to make my first foray into the web audio API. At the moment
          I'd love a simple audio equivalent of hello world. i.e. a 440HZ sine oscillator.
          From the API it seems the function to create one is "createOscillator" which
          doesn't seem to exist according to the browsers I'm using, (Canary and Firefox
          latest builds). I thought it was obtained through the AudioContext Object like
          createBufferSource() but it would appear not. Can anyone shed some light
          the matter? Thanks in advance and please find my code below:

```
    <script>
window.onload = init();

function init ()
{
if (typeof AudioContext == "function") {
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
} else if (typeof webkitAudioContext == "function") {
    var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
}

var source = audioContext.createOscillator();
source.connect(audioContext.destination);
source.start();
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's still in the [bleeding edge spec draft](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) and it exists in Chrome 30 (currently stable), so I can only assume this is a momentary hiccup. The only issue I see in your code is that `source.start` must take an argument (try it out with `source.start(0)`).

Comment: Thanks for the input, much appreciated! Can you suggest any workarounds in the meantime?

Comment: Use a less bleeding-edge version of Chrome than Canary for development, I guess. You can also file a bug at http://crbug.com/new to make sure it gets fixed promptly.